# How do I get this JSON into a python list or dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm new to Python and am writing my first python script.  I have made good progress, but I am having trouble handling the response from a web service. Here is some code that will get a sample response:

```
import urllib
import json
urlstring = 'http://geonb-t.snb.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=2219&outSR=2953&geometries=674728.283,5319788.292&transformation=1841&transformForward=TRUE&f=json'
ro1 = urllib.urlopen(urlstring)
ro2 = ro1.read()
print ro2
```

Sample response:
    `{"geometries":[{"x":2488268.7116061845,"y":7667607.8963871095}]}`

The web service response looks like a Python dictionary, but when I save it I get a string.  How do I read this response into a Python list or dictionary?  I need to extract the 'x' and 'y' values.  I am working in Python 2.6.5.

Comment: Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/json.html) module, like you imported. Look at `loads()` and `dumps()` and decide which one is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a JSON string. Use the `json` module to parse it, as in

```
json.loads(ro2)
```

Comment: Well that was simple - "ro3 = json.loads(ro2)" gives me a dictionary in variable ro3 and I can get the x and y values like this - "ro3['geometries'][0]['x']) + ',' + ro3['geometries'][0]['y']"